# UITextView not scroll properly when using TextKit

Tags: ios, uitextview, textkit

I config a textView in a UIViewController like following:
[textView configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwAuY.png)

but when controller `viewDidAppear` I found that UITextView's  `contentSize = {375, 242}` and UITextView can not scroll.

But if i tap the textView, let the textView begin editing (but edit nothing), then i touch the controller's view let textView endEditing, log the textView, this time `contentSize = {375, 361}` and UITextView can scroll.
Is anybody know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `textView` something like,

```
 UITextView *standardTextView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, self.view.frame.size.width - 40, 120)];
standardTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
standardTextView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor]CGColor];

standardTextView.delegate = self;
standardTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

[self.view addSubview:standardTextView];
```

then when your content(i.e text) will be bigger than `textview's height` it will enable scroll otherwise it remains disable!!

Comment: Yes, i know if i create textView using `initWithFrame` it can scroll, but i want to know why it didn't work using `initWithFrame:textContainer`. Is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTextContainer` has a property called `heightTracksTextView` which may be interfering with your setup here, as the default is false.

I would double check the height of the `NSTextContainer` after you initialize the `UITextView` and after you add the `UITextView` to the view hierarchy.

Check the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nstextcontainer/1444559-heighttrackstextview

If that doesn't help, let me know, I know I've solved this issue before, but I'm not at my computer right now.